# Got Uncaught TypeError: altResolution is null when the element already has something in it?

Tags: javascript, html

In my code
I have a `p` element that I want to put in the number of a input value. However when my code was like this with a content in it already I get `Uncaught TypeError: altResolution is null`
so the code causing the error is below.

```
<input id="resolution" type="text"><p> x </p><p id="alt-resolution">16</p>    // the altResolution element
```

```
const pixelInput = document.querySelector('input#resolution');
const altResolution = document.querySelector('p#alt-resolution');

pixelInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  altResolution.innerHTML = pixelInput.value;
});
```

but when I have it like this (code below) it works no errors no problem. This code has nothing in it but it works. Why is this? Thank you.

```
<p id="alt-resolution"></p> // nothing in the p tag
```

```js
const pixelInput = document.querySelector('input#resolution');
const altResolution = document.querySelector('p#alt-resolution');

pixelInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  altResolution.innerHTML = pixelInput.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="resolution" type="text"><p> x </p><p id="alt-resolution">16</p>
```

Comment: where is `altResolution` variable declared? the content in HTML does not effect JS declarations of variables

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi, i edited my comment to be more complete. Thank you. It is the selector for the p tag in the html i show

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue - works just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uctzxpsb/) - if that code doesn't work for you, that would suggest a browser issue

Comment: I've created a snippet of your code for you - seems to work fine

Comment: Your code also seems to work fine for me, I would check for typos in your id and querySelector value.

Comment: @protango  I will double check (though I did check for that) anyway thank you very much!